# adding/updating/removing item in a list with linq

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects MyObjects called CandidateListOfMyObjects and another list called InitialListOfMyObjects. I'm writing a method that updates, deletes or adds instances of MyObjects to the list with linq?

This works inside a loop:

```
MyObject ThisObject = new MyObject(); //MyObject has a field call ObjectID

for (int index = 0; index < ListOfMyObjects.Count; index++)
{
  ThisObject = null;
  ThisObject = ListOfMyObjects[index];

  if (condition)
  {
     add ThisObject to InitialListOfMyObjects
  }

  if (condition)
  {
     replace the MyObject with ID ThisObject.ID in the InitialListOfMyObjects with ThisObject
  }

  if (condition)
  {
     delete the ThisObject with ID ThisObject.ID from the InitialListOfMyObjects
  }
}
```

For now, I'm looping through the InitialListOfMyObjects but as I am looking at my code, I'm doing loops inside loops so I'm sure that's not the best way to do it.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: LINQ is designed to avoid side effects (it comes from functional programming). In other words, it's not designed to alter the original list. Instead it can create and return a new list.

Comment: So I can't do this with linq? I have to keep my loops inside loops?

Comment: Not at all. You can replace your list with a result from a Linq method call.

Comment: @sq33G: can you show me how to do one case? May be the update case? I'll be able to figure out the other cases.

Comment: If you don't get a better answer before I have access to a C# compiler, I'll try to post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your `condition` looks like, but I assume that simply replacing the original list with the updated list would not be sufficient. Here is my version of Linq sync between two lists.

```
//replace original with synchronized list
original = from updatedPair in updated
           join originalPair in original
//group join the updated to the original: 
//all updates will be included, 
//but only those originals with a matching update 
//(deletes items not in the updated list automatically)
           on updatedPair.Key equals originalPair.Key 
           into originalsForUpdate
//added items will have a null originalForUpdate
           let originalForUpdate = originalsForUpdate.DefaultIfEmpty().Single() 
           where !ConditionForDelete(updatedPair, originalForUpdate)
           select new MyObjectThingy
             { updatedPair.Key,
               ConditionForUpdate(originalForUpdate,updatedPair) ? 
                 updatedPair.Value : 
                 originalForUpdate.Value 
             }.ToList();
```

Note that while this allows for conditions on Add or Update, it has only limited conditions on Delete - anything that is only in the original list but not in the updated list will not be in the result set. To work around this, you can call `Union(original.Where(item => !updated.Any(updItem => updItem.Key == item.Key) && ConditionForUndoingDelete(item)))` before calling `ToList` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

For adding data to list using linq

```
    public void insertintolist()
    {

        var accountService = new AccountServicetest();
        var storethread = new Thread();
        storethread.TrdTopic = "JavaScript";
        storethread.EmailID = "nived@gmail.com";
        storethread.Name = "nived";
        storethread.Topic = "Function";
        storethread.Message = "what is a functio ";
        storethread.Posts = 0;
        storethread.Views = 0;
        accountService.StoreThread(storethread);

    }

    public void StoreThread(Thread model)
    { 

        if (model != null)
        {
            model.TrdTopicID = 4;
            accountcontrollertest.storethread.Add(model);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own extenstion methods. Put this method in a public static class:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var value in values)
        action(value);
}
```

It enables you to perform an action on each element of an enumerable in the LINQ style.

```
articles
    .Where(a => a.Price < 100.0)
    .ForEach(a => { a.Price *= 1.2; a.Updated = true; });
```

Comment: I heard static classes are somewhat dangerous. How does this work if 2 or more people call the extension method at the EXACT same nanosecond? Is there a way to do it without extension methods?

Comment: From what I understand static functions are fine to use, it is static variables that can be dangerous and cause conflictions if accessed/modified at the same time.

Comment: Extension methods require static classes.  If two people call the extension method at the same time, *if the extension method does not use static data*, nothing bad will happen.  Thread clashes happen if data is shared.

Comment: @Inuyasha: Ok, how is the code written so that the data is shared vs. not shared?

Comment: If two people are running your programm then two separated instances are created. This applies to the static variables and properties and everthing else as well. Even if both persons are working on the same computer (e.g. on a terminal server) and even if you start the app twice on your own computer, the different instances of the app will reside in different memory locations completely isolated from each other.

Comment: Consider using foreach rather than writing your own: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: Personally I would use a regular foreach loop, but the question was about updating an item in a list with linq.